# Android - bundletool.jar install-apks - How to reinstall apk with data/cache

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, adb, build-tools

Android [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) helps to install apks file. But install-apks is replacing app, if the app is already installed.

How to install apks file with out deleting cache/data, similar to "adb install -r" ?

```
$bundletool install-apks --apks=tmpapp-11121JEC202553.apks --allow-test-only
```

Comment: Have a look at the command's help, i.e. `bundletool help install-apks`. There's a flag as well, but I'm on my phone right now so can't check it for you.